# how can I detect the machine language in django?

Tags: python, django

So, I know that `language = request.session.get(LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY)` gets language saved to session but my question is.. Is this the language used by the computer? and if not how can I detect the language used by my computer?

Comment: This will inspect the session data for data. Only if you stored in the session, then that will contain the language.

Comment: that does not matter, browsers typically have settings to allow/prevent sending the language preferences, after all this is privacy sensitive info.

Comment: so How can I store it? should I use 'request.LANGUAGE_CODE' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will try to obtain the session variable that has as key the `LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY`, which is normally `'_language'`. Session data is stored at the *server side*, and thus this is not part of what the browser sends. Normally you here store the language the user has picked, such that you do not have to determine the language multiple times.

Usually a server aims to pick a language based on the [**`HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`** header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) in the request. This contains a list of languages that the user has configured that they understand, usually ordered from better to worse. The browser can determine that based on the locale of the machine of that user, but it is possible that you configured this manually. For example Google Chrome sometimes asks if it has to translate a language, if you select "never translate", then it might include that as a language. So the header can look for example like:

> ```
> Accept-Language: fr-CH, fr;q=0.9, en;q=0.8, de;q=0.7, *;q=0.5
> ```

So here the browser has specified that the main language is French (Switzerland), then French, English, German and then all other languages.

Django has [**`LocaleMiddleware`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.locale) that is constructed to detect a language that both the browser *and* the server accept (a language that you specify as a language for which translations exist).

You can enable the `LocaleMiddleware` in the `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py

# …

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # …
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    # …
]
```

Django has [documentation on how it determines what language to use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). In general it determines the language with:

1. the name of the language in the URL if you use an i18n url pattern;
2. the session variable with the `LANGUAGE_SESSION_COOKIE`;
3. looking for a cookie with the `django_language` name;
4. using the `Accept-Language` header and looking for the first language the server supports as well;
5. using the [**`LANGUAGE_CODE`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGE_CODE) which normally specifies the "default" language of the server.

You can obtain the language picked by the above procedure with:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

lang = get_language()
```

This is a string that specifies the language, for example `'en-us'`.

Comment: I am so sorry I am totally new to this but I read about get_language() and it says that it returns the currently selected language code. Returns None if translations are temporarily deactivated... Does they mean selected language by computer, browser or html pages?